# How to turn a variable iterable?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there any way I can turn a variable iterable in a for loop? I am trying to make a password generator and for the for loop I use a variable which is an input number.

```
for lists in(nr_letters):
    thing_ = letters[stuff]
    thing_ + other_thing
```

When I try to use a variable in a loop I get `'int' object is not iterable`.

Comment: Are you asking how to loop `n` times given an integer `n`?

Comment: Yeah I am trying to loop n times given an integer

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17647907/for-or-while-loop-to-do-something-n-times

Comment: no :c instead i get " can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str "

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Python iterate a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785490/how-does-python-iterate-a-for-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Erm...
something like

```
possible_chars = [ 'a', 'b', 'c', ...]
nr_letters = int(input('enter password length'))
password = ''
for _ in range(nr_letters):
    token = pick_at_random_from(possible_chars, 1)
    password = password + token
return password
```

Like this?

For the pick at random function you can look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choice

Following the comments I rewrote and fixed them into something functional

```
import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'] 
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!") 
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n"))
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n")) 
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

#create a list of pairs (list, number of chars)
lists = [ (letters, nr_letters), (symbols, nr_symbols), (numbers, nr_numbers)]
password = '' # this is our building block in which we accumulate the choiches

for collection, size in lists: # iterate through a list
    for _ in range(size): # For how many chars we want from that list
        i = random.randint(0, size) # pick a random index
        token = collection[i] # pick the random item using the index
        password = password + token # add the item to the password

print(password) # show the password
```

Comment: I got can "only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"

Comment: How do you select the token? Like the exact code. Because from your comment it seems that you are trying to concatenate an empty variable (None).

Comment: The variable is already filled from an input " nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) " it is done before the for line and i change my code to range "for lists in range(nr_letters):
  thing_ = letters[stuff]
  thing_ + other_thing"

Comment: Well, first off lists is a number going from 0 to `nr_letters` but is not used anywhere in the loop body, then we have `letters` which I presume is something like the `possible_chars` that I put on my answer. But the `stuff` variable from where does it come? what does it contains? Plus you assign to `thing_` a  character but immediately after you have a statement in which `other_thing` appears and their concatenation is not assigned to anything.

Comment: import random
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters= int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n"))

Sorry idk how to turn it into code in stackoverflow

Comment: nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

int(nr_letters)

thingidk = int(len(letters))

stuff = random.randint(0, thingidk)

other_thing = None 


for lists in range(nr_letters):
  thing_ = letters[stuff]
  thing_ + other_thing